# How to limit sshd/sftp connections or memory use in Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, memory-limit, ulimit

I'm working on an embedded Linux system, and I found it will report 'page allocation stall' while I'm downloading file via sftp.

Please refer to this [video](https://youtu.be/YSdW9xAGPWI) for detail.

I've tried the following ways to limit the resouce used by sshd and sftp-server, but all failed.

1. set `MaxSessions 2`, `MaxStartups 2:30:3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. add following to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
root             hard    maxlogins       2
sshd             hard    nproc           2
ssh              hard    nproc           2
```

3. set `ulimit` command as follows to limit user-space application

```
ulimit -m 1024
ulimit -u 5
ulimit -v 8192
```

Any comments/suggestion are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that limiting memory is appropriate.   The problem is definately memory related as you are getting an OOM message (visible about 2:12 in your video)- but do you have any swap set up?  Setting up even a small amount of swap - and setting vm.swappiness low or 0 can give the memory manager hints to better manage memory and could well fix the problem.   I'm not sure that constraining the memory available to ssh will do that.

Comment: Also, did you restart your server (or at least ssh) after implementing the MaxStartups command?  At about 1:54 in your video we can see more then 3 simultaneous uploads making me think that this directive has not been honoured.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the reply. I tried both restart sshd and reboot the entire system with no luck. I'm also confused about why those settings doesn't work. However, when I set MaxSessions=0, the system will close my ssh connection right after I login as root, therefore I believe the new setting has been applied to sshd, but somehow MaxSessions doesn't act as I expected.
On the otherhand, I tried setting vm.swappiness by modifying /etc/sysctl.conf, still not working. But thanks anyway.

Comment: What  does the command "free" output?